# How can I run dropzone.js for a prototype without running a server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, dropzone.js

So I'm creating a prototype that needs to run DropzoneJS (or any open-source drag-and-drop upload module) but it seems to not work without a server side to catch the upload. Is there any way for me to not have to deal with the server side and just mock the dropzone functionality as if there was a server?

Comment: What do you want to do with the files then?

Comment: Nothing. Just need to show it like it's downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then just include the the accept option like this in your dropzone configuration (It uses jQuery):

```
accept: function (file, done) {
    done('Here you can write anything');
    $('.dz-preview').last().toggleClass('dz-error dz-success');
}
```

This is going to reject all the files you put in the dropzone element and then change a class to simulate that the files have been upload to server.

Comment: Too bad I didn't see this before my deadline, but this really is what I needed. Thanks, wallek876! I however ended up hiding the error message with css and just simulated the progress animation with a setInterval function on file drop. :)